# Portlet not getting deployed properly through hot deploy

Tags: eclipse, spring, liferay, liferay-6

I have a Spring MVC portlet which I am trying to deploy through hot deploy in STS. I have configured the Liferay server runtime on my STS. But the portlet doesn't seem to be initializing properly. If I export the same portlet as a WAR to the liferay/deploy folder it works fine. What am I missing? please help.

The output which gets printed while doing hot deploy is

`Mar 28, 2014 5:43:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\SinglePortlet
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/portlet is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
Mar 28, 2014 5:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/portlet is already defined
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext/slf4j-jdk14.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext/util-java.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/SPP-SinglePortlet/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "true".
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".`

cant make out anything out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay has maven plugin to deploy the portlets. [Liferay Maven Plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.maven.plugins/liferay-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into following link it may help you,..

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/12/liferay-spring-portlet.html

Comment: Please explain how your link will help. Don't just paste a link and say "Look there"

Comment: See when ever we deploy any portlet in liferay first it should be placed in deploy folder then liferay auto deployer is responsible for add some addition configuration files and addition configuration to the portlet configuration. simply you make place in server deployment folder its wont work ok. first look into portlet configuration file or war file before deploy and after place into deploy folder and deployed in deployments directory then you can understand all. each time we need not answer all stuff in same place where you asked ok. be have patience.dont underestimate the people and thanks

Comment: Update your answer with that :P